# PyPika passing parameters to query

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, pypika

I an new to use PyPika. As per their documentation it says I can use `Parameter()` to pass parameters. [Docs](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2_tutorial.html?highlight=parameter#parametrized-queries)

I am not able to find a way to add this into the Query Builder. I am getting errors. `ValueError: ':name' is not a valid parameter name`

Sample code:

```
from pypika import functions as fn
from pypika import MSSQLQuery, Table, Field

def sample(name):
    sample= Table('sample')
    query = MSSQLQuery \
    .from_(sample) \
    .where(sample.name== Parameter(':name',Parameter.POSITIONAL_ONLY)) \
    .groupby(sample.date) \
    .select(sample.date, fn.Sum(sample.itemscount))
    print(query)
    # result = db.execute(query,params=(name))
    # data = result.fetchall()
    return query

def sample('SAMPLENAME')
```